# gparted is locked or something

Tags: software-installation, gparted

I get the following error when trying to install gparted:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Please help. I need to install an extra hard drive.
I have typed in all the stuff that everyone else has done and I still cannot get anything to do anything.

Comment: What command did you run to get this error?

Answer (score 2):

You need to run `sudo apt-get install gparted`